# glossaries-extra - Unsorted symbols with style long results in undefined control sequence?

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

When I try to use `\printunsrtglossary` with using the built-in `symbols` glossary, and try to apply `style=long` I get an `Undefined control sequence` error on the `\printunsrtglossary` line. Interestingly enough, the document seems to compile with the symbols glossary correctly printed in long style. Why is this resulting in an error and how I resolve it? Thank you for your time!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary[title={Notation},type=symbols,style=long]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What version of `glossaries-extra` (and `glossaries`) do you have? Your MWE works fine with `glossaries-extra` v1.25 and `glossaries` v4.35.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, Ah! A simple upgrade does fix the issue. I was using `glossaries-extra` v1.18 (I unfortunately didn't glance at the `glossaries` version before updating). Upgrading to the latest (v1.26) fixes the problem. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it for anyone else who might have this trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a bug in an earlier version of [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) (or [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)). It works fine with the latest versions of both packages.

Unrelated, I recommend you use `sort=none,nogroupskip` when no sorting is required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbols,sort=none,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={position}]{x}{\ensuremath{x}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={velocity}]{v}{\ensuremath{v}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={acceleration}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={time}]{t}{\ensuremath{t}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={force}]{F}{\ensuremath{F}}

\begin{document}

\printunsrtglossary[title={Notation},type=symbols,style=long]

\end{document}
```